# Rouche's theorem problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the polynomial $z^n + nz-1$ has $n$ zeroes inside the circle with centre at $0$ and radius $1+\sqrt{2/(n-1)}$ for $n=3,4,\dotsc$

Please give me some hints as to how to apply Rouche's nicely without expanding binomials with square roots all over the place? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:Do you know this one? $
(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$

take $f(z)=z^n, g(z)=nz-1$ then show that $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ on $|z|=1+\sqrt{{2\over(n-1)}}$

Hence $f, f+g$ has same number of root inside the specified circle

Comment: Yes.. You just take the first two terms in the binomial... thanks

Comment: Yes @user71815... *and* assume $\,x>-1\,$ . It is called Bernoulli's inequality. You should also, imo, upvote this answer if you find it helpful. I know I did, so +1

Comment: Wait.. If you do $|z|^n > 1 + n \sqrt{2/(n-1)}$, then that doesn't work because $|g(-1-\sqrt{2/(n-1)})| = n+1 + n\sqrt{2/(n-1)}$?

Comment: Turns out you need the $x^2$ term! i.e. $(1+x)^n > 1 + nx + n(n-1)x^2/2$. Thanks everybody